# C# MediatR error: Register your handlers with the container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, handler, mediator, mediatr

Every time that i try to call *Send* from *MediatR* to any Query/Command that i have, it returns this Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[CQRSHost.Recursos.Queries.GetTodosProdutosQuery,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CQRSHost.Models.Produto]]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples.'

Inner Exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve 'MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[CQRSHost.Recursos.Queries.GetTodosProdutosQuery,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CQRSHost.Models.Produto]]' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'CQRSHost.Context.AppDbContext'.

But i have the *AppDbContext* in my DI container:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .ConfigureHostConfiguration(hostConfig =>
            {
                hostConfig.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                hostConfig.AddEnvironmentVariables("DSO_");
            })
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton(ConfigureLogger());
                services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    "Server=localhost;Database=newdatabase;User Id=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd!@#$%;",
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(AppDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));

                services.AddHostedService<NewService>();

                //services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                //services.AddMediatR(typeof(GetTodosProdutosQuery).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
                services.AddMediatR(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
            });
    }
```

Here is the service that i use to call the query:

```
public class NewService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public NewService(ILogger logger, IMediator mediator)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var command = new GetTodosProdutosQuery();
        var response = await _mediator.Send(command);

        _logger.Information($"First Name: {response.First()?.Nome}");
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And here is what my project looks like:
[ProjectImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xhcw.png)

The commented lines is what i've already tryied to solve.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I think Hosted Services don't declare scopes. As DbContext is scoped, you might want to use DbContextFactory instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor or create a scope manually https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service

Comment: Can you show your handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception "Register your handlers with the container." is misleading. The real error is described in the inner exception:

> Cannot resolve 'MediatR.IRequestHandler<GetTodosProdutosQuery, IEnumerable>' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'CQRSHost.Context.AppDbContext'.

This happens because you inject the `IMediator` into a singleton consumer `NewService`. The `Mediator` implementation depends on a `IServiceProvider` but as `NewService` is singleton, it is resolved from the root container, and so will all its dependencies recursively. This means that once `Mediator` starts resolving from its `IServiceProvider`, it also resolves from the root container. And scoped services can't be resolved from the root container, because that would lead to bugs, because that scoped service would be cached for the lifetime of the root container, and reused for the lifetime of the root  container - which means indefinitely.

The solution is to inject an `IServiceScope` into `NewService` create a scope from within its `StartAsync` and resolve the `IMediator` from there:

```cs
public class NewService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _container;

    public NewService(IServiceProvider container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await using (var scope = _container.CreateScope())
        {
            var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger>();
            var mediator = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();

            var command = new GetTodosProdutosQuery();
            var response = await mediator.Send(command);

            logger.Information($"First Name: {response.First()?.Nome}");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Another, perhaps more convenient option would be to ensure that the mediator always resolves from a new scope. This can be achieved using the following code:

```cs
public record ScopedSender<TSender>(IServiceProvider Provider)
    : ISender where TSender : ISender
{
    public Task<TResponse> Send<TResponse>(
        IRequest<TResponse> request, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        async using (var scope = Provider.CreateScope());
        var sender = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TSender>();
        return await sender.Send(request, ct);
    }
    
    public Task<object?> Send(object request, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        async using (var scope = Provider.CreateScope());
        var sender = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TSender>();
        return await sender.Send(request, ct);
    }
    
    public IAsyncEnumerable<TResponse> CreateStream<TResponse>(
        IStreamRequest<TResponse> request, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        async using (var scope = Provider.CreateScope());
        var sender = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TSender>();
        return await sender.CreateStream(request, ct);
    }
    
    public IAsyncEnumerable<object?> CreateStream(object request, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        async using (var scope = Provider.CreateScope());
        var sender = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TSender>();
        return await sender.CreateStream(request, ct);
    }
}
```

Now configure this as follows:

```cs
services.AddMediatR(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
services.AddTransient<Mediator>();
services.AddSingleton<ISender, ScopedSender<Mediator>>();
```

Now you can safely inject your `ISender` into yout `NewService` without having to apply scoping:

```cs
public class NewService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IMediator _sender;

    public NewService(ILogger logger, ISender sender)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _sender = sender;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var command = new GetTodosProdutosQuery();
        var response = await _sender.Send(command);

        _logger.Information($"First Name: {response.First()?.Nome}");
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first option still gives me the same error after handling the IMediator from the scope. Then i used the second option. After some adjusts it worked as expected, thank you very much Steven :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, I solved it here by changing AddScoped to AddSingleton and adding builder.Services.AddTransient();